# Convert a string to a list of length one

Tags: python, string, list, split

I created a method that requires a list in order to work properly.  However, you can send in a list OR a simple string.  I want to turn that string into a list that contains that entire string as an element.  For example, if I have:

```
"I am a string"
```

I want to convert that to:

```
["I am a string"]
```

I am able to do it like so:

```
"I am a string".split("!@#$%^&*")
```

Because I will never have that combination of symbols, it will always convert it to a list without removing any characters.  However, this doesn't seem like that great of a way to do it. Is there another way?

Comment: If you want to use a cleaner version of `.split()`, you can set the `maxsplit` parameter to `0` so you will be guaranteed to get the whole string back: `"I am a string".split(' ',0)`

Comment: I like that much better than what I did, and I'm pretty sure that would be useful sometime in the future, so thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> "abc"
'abc'
>>> ["abc"]
['abc']
>>> abc = "abc"
>>> abc
'abc'
>>> [abc]
['abc']
>>> "I am a string".split("!@#$%^&*") == ["I am a string"]
True
```

Putting the value in square brackets makes a list with one item, just as multiple values makes a list with multiple items. The only container which does not follow this pattern is the tuple, as the round brackets are also used for grouping. In that case, just add a comma after the single item:

```
>>> abc
'abc'
>>> (abc)
'abc'
>>> (abc,)
('abc',)
```

If you want your function to handle list and strings differently under the cover, code your function like:

```
def f(maybe_list):
    if not isinstance(maybe_list, list):
        maybe_list = [maybe_list]
    # carry on, you have a list.
```

Comment: I think OP is asking how to accept either a string or a list of strings as an argument

Comment: @ohruunuruus Well, his title is `Convert a string to a list of length one`, which is _exactly_ what I have covered. We may be hitting an XY problem though. I've added on, JIC.

Comment: sorry for the poor title header; what matsjoyce did properly answered my question, though.  I didn't realize you could just put a string in brackets... Thanks

Comment: @user2869231 Don't worry, the titles always the hardest.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to accept either a single string *or* a list of strings as the input to a function, but then want to ensure that you're always working with a list in subsequent portions of code, you can check the type of the argument and convert if necessary:

```
def listify(arg):
    return arg if isinstance(arg, list) else [arg] 

listify("hello")
['hello']

listify(["hi", "howdy"])
['hi', 'howdy']
```

This doesn't have to occur as a separate function, I just put it in a function to illustrate quickly. You can also directly assign to a variable instead of returning.

Comment: Although type-checking isn't considered "pythonic", when you do it, it's best to be as non-specific and generic as possible as illustrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66485952/355230).

Comment: Thanks, that is definitely an improvement.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> s = "abc"
>>> if isinstance(s, str): 
...    s = [ s ]
>>> s 
['abc']
```

As proposed earlier, you can make this check a separate function.

You can also write a one-liner using a ternary operator (introduced since Python 2.5):

```
s = s if isinstance(s, list) else [ s ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one quick way:

```
#!python
myString = 'some string'
myList = list()
myList.append(myString)
```

... note that `.append()` adds a single item to a list while `.extend()` adds a sequence of items to a list.

The problem you're encountering is that a Python string is also a sequence of characters (and is thus an "iterable").  So something like: `list(myString)` treats `myString` like it would treat any other iterable.  (Conceptually that's done by instantiating an empty list, iterating over the initialization contents and appending each to the newly instantiated list).