# Is it possible to prevent a string from being treated like a list?

Tags: python

Is there any syntax in python to ensure that a given string is not processed as a list? I periodically end up seeing strings iterated through as a list of characters when not intended.  If there were some way to say

```
do_not_convert_to_list(some_string)
```

Then if a for- or dictionary- comprehension were written not quite correctly an error might be thrown instead of performing an incorrect operation. The former would be preferable: is it possible?

Comment: Strings and lists are both iterable sequences. I suppose you could always do a type check: `isinstance(obj, str)`.

Comment: You can subclass `str` and override `__iter__` to raise an error. Of course this would only affect instances of the subclass.

Comment: @interjay the strings are being dynamically generated e.g. by `split()` so yea that might be tricky

Comment: Just give it time, with more experience you're not going to make these mistakes anymore.  Better learn and understand what you're doing than relying on some hack.  If you don't make the mistakes and troubleshoot the effects yourself, you'll be even more helpless in the future when your programs get larger.

Comment: @AlainT. Plenty of time sunk into python gotchas.  Generators instead of lists is a fun one to deal with in nested comprehensions.  "Troubleshooting". Yea that's real easy to do in nested comprehensions when python lambdas do not either support statements or multi-lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible workaround that leverages the fact that strings aren't mutable.

It doesn't throw an `Exception`, but instead merely converts the object into a `list`.

```
from collections.abc import MutableSequence

def listify(obj):
    return obj if isinstance(obj, MutableSequence) else [obj]

something = 'Monty'

for elem in listify(something):
    ...
```

I got the basic idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29854268/355230).

Comment: I haven't been able to parse that logic correctly but it's just me: it does work properly
```x = [ a for a in listify(something)]  # "['Monty']"```

Comment: @Stephen: Effectively the function just returns its argument if it's list-like otherwise it creates a single element list containing it and returns that.